# Determine Epsilon for identification

Tags: data-mining, databases

I have a project in which I need to compare different distances in a database with a distance in input in order to identify a person. For that I use this expression: DistanceDB - DistanceInput < epsilon, if this is true then the distance and information in the Database row are related to the person standing before the kinect. How can I choose epsilon because if it's too small, no one will be identifier, and if it's too big the application will return the first row of the database. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I don't think this can be answered from the data you give.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to start with a value that seems reasonable and improve it by trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have a parameter that you don't know how to set, you should probably tune it based on sample or training data.